# Flutter : Handling Performance after adding a listview to another listview

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

iam trying to add a listview to another ListView.Builder

and i have a lot of data to display in it
and every ListView have More than 5 Horizontal ListViews

the problem that to add a listview to Another i have to make it

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

the problem that this gonna make the performance so heavy
so is there any way to handle its Performance

thank you

Comment: Why you might need to add a listview to another ListView.Builder?

Comment: this is because a nested `ListView.builder` builds all the items you have - do NOT use it that way - instead use `CustomScrollView` and multiple `SliverList`s

Comment: @pskink thank you .. can you add your comment as an answer to mark it

Comment: great, post a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

as @psKink answer

this is because a nested ListView.builder builds all the items you have - do NOT use it that way - instead use CustomScrollView and multiple SliverLists